# Remote Viewing Software

Tags: windows, website, web, remote-control, kiosk

I'm looking for some software and having a difficult time finding what exactly I require.

What I would like is to run on a central computer somewhere, a piece of software that I would like particular users to be able to simply view that screen on their desktops via (preferably) a web browser.

This is similar to Remote Control software, however, the end users are not able to control - simply view the screen.  This way they cannot interact with this software.

The application I want to view is a Windows based software, so something in Linux is not going to be the best solution - unless I can get the application to somehow run in Linux.

Any possible suggestions?

Comment: logmein.com has a free option, and its possible they have a viewonly mode.

Comment: @TobyAllen - I'm pretty sure that LogMeIn.com has a timeout.  

I was able to use RealVNC to accomplish what I required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used [RealVNC](http://www.realvnc.com) to create `View Only` screens. It opens in it's own window rather than a web browser, but it has options to be set up to use a web browser.

Page 93 of the [VNC User Guide](http://www.realvnc.com/products/vnc/documentation/5.0/guides/user/VNC_User_Guide.pdf) has instructions how to restrict functionality.

Comment: Note that RealVNC is about $30 for non-personal use.

Comment: I was able to purchase RealVNC and implement it for this purpose successfully.  Thanks @CharlieRB!

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for something fairly static, such as a status panel or something, you could create a simple script to take a screenshot of the "shared" computer every .5 seconds, and have it save to a simple webpage hosted on Apache or IIS. You could use a bit of javascript to make the page refresh every second, or possibly get a little more involved.

Just found this [This](http://www.nchsoftware.com/screen/index.html). ScreenStream. FAQ says its totally free, as in can be used for a business. Looks like something you might be able to use.

Comment: That's a great idea, @lexvegas - however - this software already does it's own updating. I would *prefer* if the users were just simply able to view a live feed.  Appreciate that idea though.